# Javascript: return a bound input that is the result of a previous input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bind, keyup

I am new to Javascript and am having trouble understanding why my bind event does not happen.

I have simple form that will add and dynamically update the subTotal and Total of the input.

The Subtotals update correctly but the only way to get the main total is to manually update (clicking or writing something in one of the subtotals).

I need the total to be updated at dynamically as well.

I use "change keyup keydown paste" for the final total as well as the subtotals. I feel this is where my problem lies but can not find an answer.

Here is a fiddle of my setup:
http://jsfiddle.net/U8a8Y/

HTML:

```
1. Price: <input type='text' class='p1' value='0'>Rate: <input type='text' class='r1' value='0'>SUB TOTAL: <input type='text' class='tot1' value='0'><br>
2. Price: <input type='text' class='p2' value='0'>Rate: <input type='text' class='r2' value='0'>SUB TOTAL: <input type='text' class='tot2' value='0'><br>
3. Price: <input type='text' class='p3' value='0'>Rate: <input type='text' class='r3' value='0'>SUB TOTAL: <input type='text' class='tot3' value='0'><br>

4.TOTAL: <input type='text' class='total' value='0'>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {     
     var p1 = $(".p1");
     var r1 = $(".r1");
     var tot1 = $(".tot1");

     var p2 = $(".p2");
     var r2 = $(".r2");
     var tot2 = $(".tot2");

     var p3 = $(".p3");
     var r3 = $(".r3");
     var tot3 = $(".tot3");

     var total = $(".total");
// SUB TOTAL
    //1.
     $([p1[0], r1[0]]).bind("change keyup keydown paste", function(e) {
            var Result1;
            Result1 = parseFloat(r1.val()) + parseFloat(p1.val());
            tot1.val(Result1);
        });
    //2.    
     $([p2[0], r2[0]]).bind("change keyup keydown paste", function(e) {
            var Result2;
            Result2 = parseFloat(r2.val()) + parseFloat(p2.val());
            tot2.val(Result2);
        });
    //3.    
     $([p3[0], r3[0]]).bind("change keyup keydown paste", function(e) {
            var Result3;
            Result3 = parseFloat(r3.val()) + parseFloat(p3.val());
            tot3.val(Result3);
        });

    //4. MAIN TOTAL
     $([tot1[0], tot2[0], tot3[0]]).bind("change keyup keydown paste", function(e) {
            var Result4;
            Result4 = parseFloat(tot1.val()) + parseFloat(tot2.val()) + parseFloat(tot3.val());
            total.val(Result4);
    }); 

});
```

Any hints on why this is not working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function to calculate total and call it when you are calculating sub-total.
See below query :

```
jQuery(function($) {
     // input variables go here

     var p1 = $(".p1");
     var r1 = $(".r1");
     var tot1 = $(".tot1");

     var p2 = $(".p2");
     var r2 = $(".r2");
     var tot2 = $(".tot2");

     var p3 = $(".p3");
     var r3 = $(".r3");
     var tot3 = $(".tot3");

     var total = $(".total");
// SUB TOTAL
    //1.
     $([p1[0], r1[0]]).bind("change keyup keydown paste", function(e) {
            var Result1;
            Result1 = parseFloat(r1.val()) + parseFloat(p1.val());
            tot1.val(Result1);
          calculateTotal();
        });
    //2.    
     $([p2[0], r2[0]]).bind("change keyup keydown paste", function(e) {
            var Result2;
            Result2 = parseFloat(r2.val()) + parseFloat(p2.val());
            tot2.val(Result2);
          calculateTotal();
        });
    //3.    
     $([p3[0], r3[0]]).bind("change keyup keydown paste", function(e) {
            var Result3;
            Result3 = parseFloat(r3.val()) + parseFloat(p3.val());
            tot3.val(Result3);
         calculateTotal();
        });
// function to calculate total
var calculateTotal = function()
{
     var Result4;
            Result4 = parseFloat(tot1.val()) + parseFloat(tot2.val()) + parseFloat(tot3.val());
            total.val(Result4);
}   
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U8a8Y/4/)**

Comment: Perfect Answer. Very clear and understandable response. Thanks a lot.